# Custom navigation with Navigator component in React-Native

Tags: javascript, ios, navigation, reactjs, react-native

I’m exploring possibilities of [React Native](http://facebook.github.io/react-native) while developing a demo app with custom navigation between views with the help of [`Navigator` component](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content).

The main app class renders navigator and inside `renderScene` returns passed component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{name: 'WelcomeView', component: WelcomeView}}
                configureScene={() => {
                    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
                }}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                    // count the number of func calls
                    console.log(route, navigator); 

                    if (route.component) {
                        return React.createElement(route.component, { navigator });
                    }
                }}
             />
        );
    }
}
```

For now app contains two views:

```
class FeedView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>
                    Feed View!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class WelcomeView extends React.Component {
    onPressFeed() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            name: 'FeedView',
            component: FeedView
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome View!
                </Text>

                <Text onPress={this.onPressFeed.bind(this)}>
                    Go to feed!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

What I want to figure out is:

- I see in the logs that when pressing “go to feed” `renderScene` is called several times though the view renders correctly once. Is it how the animation works?

  ```
  index.ios.js:57 Object {name: 'WelcomeView', component: function}
  index.ios.js:57 Object {name: 'FeedView', component: function}
  // renders Feed View
  ```
- Generally does my approach conform to the React way, or can it be done better?

What I want to achieve is something similar to [`NavigatorIOS`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#content) but without the navigation bar (however some views will have their own custom navigation bar).

Comment: @ericvicenti this example should be included on the [Navigator page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content) in the docs. It's more complete and gives a better picture of how to use the Navigator component in context.

Comment: Just trying your example, should the scene automatically change when a navigator push happens ? For me your example never shows the Feed View! text, so I'm wondering if something has changed with recent versions.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your approach should work great. In big apps at Fb, we avoid calling the `require()` for the scene component until we render it, which can save a bit of start-up time.

The `renderScene` function should be called when the scene is first pushed to the Navigator. It will also be called for the active scene when the Navigator gets re-rendered. If you see `renderScene` get called multiple times after a `push`, then it is probably a bug.

The navigator is still a work in progress, but if you find any problems with it please file on github and tag me! (@ericvicenti)

Comment: Hello @Eric please have look on this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538306/navigate-user-to-new-screen-on-listitem-click-react-native

Answer (score 4):

`Navigator` is deprecated now in `RN 0.44.0` you can use `react-native-deprecated-custom-components` instead to support your existing application that is using `Navigator`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have previously mentioned, Navigator has been deprecated since v0.44, but can still be imported to support older applications:

> Navigator has been removed from the core React Native package in
>   version 0.44. The module has been moved to a
>   [react-native-custom-components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.43/navigator.html) package that can be imported by your
>   application in order to maintain backwards compatibility.
>
> To see the original docs for Navigator, please switch to an older version of 
>   the docs.

As per the docs (React Native v0.54) [Navigating Between Screens](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html). It is now recommended to use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started.html) if you are just getting started, or [NavigatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html) for non-Android applications

> If you are just getting started with navigation, you will probably
>   want to use **React Navigation**. React Navigation provides an easy to use 
>   navigation solution, with the ability to present common stack navigation and 
>   tabbed navigation patterns on both iOS and Android.
>
> ...
>
> If you're only targeting iOS, you may want to also check out **NavigatorIOS** 
>   as a way of providing a native look and feel with minimal configuration, as it 
>   provides a wrapper around the native UINavigationController class.

**NB**: At the time of providing this answer, React Native was at version 0.54

Answer (score 0):

Navigator component is deprecated now. You could use react-native-router-flux by askonov, it has a huge variety and supports many different animations and is efficient