# React-native: this.navigator.pop not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native. I used the react-native-navbar package to go back to the previous route [navbar component for react-native](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar)

when I click on the navbar button it shows me an error "`undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.navigator.pop')`"

here is my snippet:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} = React;
var NavigationBar = require('react-native-navbar');
var Demo = React.createClass({
    render: function()
    {
        var leftButtonConfig = {
          title: 'Back',
          handler: function onNext() {
            this.navigator.pop();
          }
        };

        var titleConfig = {
          title: 'Hello world page!',
        };
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
      <NavigationBar
        title={titleConfig}
        leftButton={leftButtonConfig} />

            <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>
        Hello World
        </Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
});
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});

module.exports = Demo;
```

Comment: Are you using a `Navigator` in any other component ? Can you show us the code for your navigator ? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335523/react-native-custom-navigation-with-navigator-component) for a working example of `Navigator`

Comment: You don't have navigator in your scope. Try to use this.props.navigator instead.

Comment: the problem is solved i just need to put `this` in a variable. I put `this` as: `let context = this;` and called it as: `context.props.navigator.pop();`

Answer (score 1):

this does not work
onPress={() => navigation.pop()}

So, use this:

onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call it as a prop.

As they uses in their [example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar/blob/master/examples/Routing/components/CustomScreen.js)

```
this.props.navigator.pop()
```

When routing the navigation uses to pass as props to the components to make easier when to make a pop to the screens stack. btw, [wix-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) can be an alternative to this, and the have a good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to react native navigation 7.0.0 documentation, you need to `import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';` then on back button click you need to write  `Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId, {         component: { name: 'ComponentName',    } })`