# Navigate user to New Screen on listitem click React native

Tags: android, listview, react-native, navigation, react-router

I am **trying to navigate user to next screen when user click on list item**. I am trying to make use of Navigator in this , **i am newbie to react , there is Redux and Flux two different architecture as i am not every much good in react so i am little confuse with there working**.We can navigate user by using **Navigator and also by using Action**. Here is my class :-

ERROR i am Getting is :- **undefined is not a function(evaluating '_this4.goDetailPage(rowData)')**

**Today.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import {FeedStack} from './movielistdeatilrouter';

export default class TodayView extends Component {
 constructor(props , context) {
      super(props , context);
    }
   render() {
        return (
<FeedStack />
        );
    }
 }
```

**movielistdeatilrouter.js** : -

```
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MovieDeatilScreen from './MovieDeatilScreen';
import Movielisting from './movielisting';
export const FeedStack = StackNavigator({
  Movielisting: {
    screen: Movielisting,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Movielisting',
    },
  },
  MovieDeatilScreen: {
    screen: MovieDeatilScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'MovieDeatilScreen',
    }),
  },
});
```

**movielistiing.js** :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import home  from '../images/home.png';
import MovieDeatilScreen from './MovieDeatilScreen'
const { width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight } = Dimensions.get('window');
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';
const uri = 'http://csswrap.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/showmenu.png';
export default class Movielisting extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
     this.state = {
       moviesData: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
     };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       this.fetchMoviesData();
     }
      fetchMoviesData() {
          var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=17e62b78e65bd6b35f038505c1eec409';
          fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(jsonData => {
              this.setState({
                moviesData: this.state.moviesData.cloneWithRows(jsonData.results),

              });
            })
          .catch( error => console.log('Error fetching: ' + error) );
        }
  render() {
        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>

                    <ListView
                      dataSource={this.state.moviesData}
                            renderRow={this.renderRow}
                            enableEmptySections={true}
                             style={styles.ListViewcontainer}
                          />
                    </View>
        );
    }
    renderRow(rowData){
            return (
              <View style={styles.thumb} >
              <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.goDeatilPage(rowData)}>
                <Image
                  source={{uri:'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h281_bestv2/'+rowData.poster_path}}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  style={styles.img} />
                  <Text style={styles.txt}>{rowData.title} (Rating: {Math.round( rowData.vote_average * 10 ) / 10})</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

            );
          }
goDeatilPage = (rowData) => {
   alert('hi');
   AsyncStorage.setItem('moviesData', JSON.stringify(rowData));
       this.props.navigation.navigate('MovieDeatilScreen');
     };
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  position:'relative',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },action: {
                                        flex: 0.4,
                                    },thumb: {
                                          backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                                          marginBottom: 5,
                                          elevation: 1
                                        },
                                        img: {
                                          height: 300
                                        },
                                        txt: {
                                          margin: 10,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          textAlign: 'left'
                                        },ListViewcontainer:{
                                         marginTop:50,
                                          bottom: 50,
                                        }
});
```

**Index.android.js** :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import App from './app';
import DrawerMenu from './Drawer/drawer-toolbar-android';
import BookmarkView from './Pages/bookmark';
import CalendarView from './Pages/calendar';
import ClientView from './Pages/client';
import InfoView from './Pages/info';
import SettingsView from './Pages/setting';
import { DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


const stackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Info: { screen: InfoView },
  Settings: {screen: SettingsView },
  Bookmark: {screen: BookmarkView },
  Calendar: {screen: CalendarView},
  Client: {screen: ClientView},
}, {
  headerMode: 'none'
});

const easyRNRoute = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: App,
  },
  Stack: {
    screen: stackNavigator
  }
}, {
  contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    style: {
      flex: 1,
      paddingTop: 15,
    }
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('flightbot', () => easyRNRoute);
```

**App.js class** :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Navigator, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

import { COLOR, ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-material-ui';
import { Toolbar, BottomNavigation, Icon } from 'react-native-material-ui';
import Container from './Container';

import { TabRouter } from 'react-navigation';

import TodayView from './Contents/today';
import ProfileView from './Contents/profile';
import MapView from './Contents/map';
import ChatView from './Contents/chat';

const uiTheme = {
  palette: {
    primaryColor: COLOR.green500,
    accentColor: COLOR.pink500,
  },
  toolbar: {
    container: {
      height: 70,
      paddingTop: 20
    }
  }
}

const TabRoute = TabRouter({
  Today: { screen: TodayView },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileView },
  Map: { screen: MapView },
  Chat: {screen: ChatView}
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'Today',
  }
);

class TabContentNavigator extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      active: props.value.active,
    };
  }

  //this method will not get called first time
  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.setState({
      active: newProps.value.active,
    }); 
  }

  render() {
    const Component = TabRoute.getComponentForRouteName(this.state.active);
    return <Component/>;
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      active: 'Today',
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Menu',
  };

  navigate() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
        <Container>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />

          <Toolbar
            leftElement="menu"
            centerElement={this.state.active}
            onLeftElementPress={() => this.navigate()}
          />

          <TabContentNavigator value={this.state} key={this.state} />

          <BottomNavigation active={this.state.active}
            hidden={false}
            style={{ container: { position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 } }}
          >
            <BottomNavigation.Action
              key="Today"
              icon="today"
              label="Today"
              onPress={() => this.setState({ active: 'Today' })}
            />
            <BottomNavigation.Action
              key="Profile"
              icon="person"
              label="Profile"
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ active: 'Profile' });
              }}
            />
            <BottomNavigation.Action
              key="Map"
              icon="map"
              label="Map"
              onPress={() => this.setState({ active: 'Map' })}
            />
            <BottomNavigation.Action
              key="Chat"
              icon="chat"
              label="Chat"
              onPress={() => this.setState({ active: 'Chat' })}
            />
          </BottomNavigation>

        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

i am trying my level best to solve this , its almost 3 days today i am looking for solution that how i can do this , i just want to open a new Screen on click on list item. Can any one tell me how to do that.I will be very Grateful if some one let me know the way to navigate to next screen.

ScreenShot of my Error :-

[image]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Using "React Navigation" should help you to do the trick.

For more information, you can find it here: https://reactnavigation.org

Cheers,

====== UPDATE ======

I believe the way you set up the Today component is incorrect, and also your question is unclear, it took me a while to understand what you're wanting to do.

Anyway, Today component should be a StackNavigator if you want to open a detail screen from it, and it will control 2 screens (ListScreen and DetailScreen):

```
const TodayView = StackNavigator({
  List: {
    screen: ListScreen,
  },
  Detail: {
    screen: DetailScreen,
  },
});
```

Then setup your screens like this:

```
class ListScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'List',
  }

  constructor(props , context) {
    super(props , context);
    this.goToDetailScreen = this.goToDetailScreen.bind(this);
  }

  goToDetailScreen() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.goToDetailScreen()}>
        <Text>GO TO DETAIL</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Detail',
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
        <Text>BACK TO LIST SCREEN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

There is an example calling "StacksInTabs" in their Github repo, that you might want to take a look at it: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/StacksInTabs.js

Cheers,

Comment: Hello @Goon , Thanks for your reply man, yes i have seen this earlier , the thing is the above class is under my TabRouter , and when i try to declare  *const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;* it gives me error as Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate) , let me post my remaining classes , i am studing from one link and trying under stand the flow., Please have look on my updated Question.And let me how to use this approach in above class. Thanks

Comment: Just update the answer, let me know if it worked @sid :)

Comment: Hey @Goon , i am little confused the problem is in Today.js class i am not able to call the navigator using onpress Event inside RenderRow function , i have also updated my App.js file as you mentioned above but still not able to navigate to Detail screen on click on ListItem .

Comment: yes , i have studied the link , and have changed my flow accordingly the same way you mentioned , but my function not getting called , i know i might be doing some silly mistake let me update my question for you.

Comment: Hey @GoonNguyen. Thanks for your reply. The Git repo which you shared at the last is not accessible. Can you please update that link? Thanks

Comment: @AbhilashRamteke Sorry I'm not the owner of that repo, they might update and remove that example, it's more than 3 years tho...

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works , this is how i do following change in code . :-

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                    <ListView
                      dataSource={this.state.moviesData}
                            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                            enableEmptySections={true}
                             style={styles.ListViewcontainer}
                          />
                    </View>
```

**I just added .bind(this) function to renderRow.**

Rest is Same :-

```
renderRow(rowData){
            return (
              <View style={styles.thumb} >
              <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>this.goDeatilPage(rowData)}>
                <Image
                  source={{uri:'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h281_bestv2/'+rowData.poster_path}}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  style={styles.img} />
                  <Text style={styles.txt}>{rowData.title} (Rating: {Math.round( rowData.vote_average * 10 ) / 10})</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

            );
          }
goDeatilPage = (rowData) => {
   alert('hi');
   AsyncStorage.setItem('moviesData', JSON.stringify(rowData));
       this.props.navigation.navigate('MovieDeatilScreen');
     }
```

Thanks @Goon for your Time i highly Appreciate your effort. Thank you Brother.

Comment: Told ya, man. I did trying to tell you to check the binding function at the very first time :D

Comment: Glad it could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use React Navigation for navigate screen, it is very Easy-to-Use,

- Create 3 class in react native

> 1. defined navigator class
>      2.first screen
>      3.navigate screen

1.Basic.js

```
    import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const BasicApp = StackNavigator({
  Main: {screen: Movielistiing},
  Detail: {screen: Movielistdeatilrouter},
});
module.exports = BasicApp;
```

2.Movielistiing.js

```
class Movielistiing extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to movie detail"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Detail', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

3.Movielistdeatilrouter.js

```
class Movielistdeatilrouter extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.name,
  });
  render() {
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go back"
        onPress={() => goBack()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```